# Spark:How we access in memory table in other sessions.

Tags: apache-spark

I am new in Spark, So i want to know how we access in memory table in other spark scala shell session.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could save the data to file (csv, parquet) in one shell then read the data from other shell

Comment: Thanks for your comments Minh Ha but we need to do transformation on in memory table, So creating csv and parquet file will hurt the performance, I don't think so this is the right way to do.

Answer (score 1):

So that's not currently supported. If you want to share RDD's between jobs you should take a look at either IBM's Spark Kernel project or the Ooyola Spark Job Server which allows for sharing a Spark Context between multiple applications.

Comment: I've ran two spark-shell application. But there is one application is running for 2nd it's showing waiting status on UI. Is there any way to run both aplication. I tried following in spark-env.sh export SPARK_EXECUTOR_MEMORY=2G
export SPARK_WORKER_CORES=4
export SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=2G
export SPARK_WORKER_INSTANCES=2